# How to define a new counter independent of section

Tags: theorems, counters, exercises

I am trying to create exercises within a paper, by which the numbering will be as one would expect (1, 2, 3, ...). However, when defining a new counter and theoremstyle:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheoremstyle{exercise}
  {\topsep}   % above space
  {\topsep}   % below space
  {\it}  % body font
  {0pt}       % indent
  {\bfseries} % head font
  {}         % head punctuation
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
  {}          % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC

\theoremstyle{exercise}
\newcounter{exercises}
\def\theexercises{}

\newtheorem{exer}{Exercise}[exercises]

\begin{document}

\begin{exer}\end{exer}

\end{document}
```

This code results in a counter with periods before the values without the line

[image]

How do I get rid of the period the precedes the counter? Also, if it helps, without the line

```
\def\theexercises{}
```

the counter will have the leading zero, right before the period.

Comment: You're using the `\newtheorem` the wrong way: `\newtheorem{exer}[exercises]{Exercise}`, mind the order of the arguments and their meanings. But in fact, the `\newtheorem{exer}{Exercise}` would define the `exer` counter automatically. The first version just tells to use another counter which is already predefined

Comment: Thank you so much! I will upvote your answer as soon as I have sufficient reputation.

Comment: The counter `exer` is "chained" to the counter `exercises`, but the latter isn't being stepped. Hence the `.1, `.2`, `.3`, look.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `\newtheorem` command has two mutually exclusive optional arguments, their meaning depending on the position:

1. `\newtheorem{foo}{Foo}` defines the environment `foo`, a counter named `foo` and entitles it `Foo`
2. `\newtheorem{foo}[otherfoo]{Foo}` defines the environment `foo`, uses (shares) the already existing counter `otherfoo` and the title `Foo`
3. `\newtheorem{foo}{Foo}[otherfoo]` does the definition as in 1), but tells to define the counter `foo` being driven by `otherfoo`, i.e. it's reset if `otherfoo` is stepped (like being defined `\newcounter{foo}[otherfoo]`, compare the standard chapter/section behaviour)

---

So, either use version 1) or 2). The first version is to be preferred if the environment should have a new counter, the second, if the counter already exists.

You can see the difference by explicitly setting the `exercises` counter to `19`, just for example.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheoremstyle{exercise}
  {\topsep}   % above space
  {\topsep}   % below space
  {\itshape}  % body font
  {0pt}       % indent
  {\bfseries} % head font
  {}         % head punctuation
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
  {}          % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC

\theoremstyle{exercise}
\newcounter{exercises}


\setcounter{exercises}{19} % Just for demonstration

\newtheorem{exer}[exercises]{Exercise}

\newtheorem{exers}{Exer}


\begin{document}

\begin{exer}\end{exer}


\begin{exers}
This is the exers env with counter number \theexers
\end{exers}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Body font should be set with `\itshape`, not with `\it`.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti: Yes, that was in the original version of the OP... I did not change because it's not important for the question, but I changed it now

Comment: Of course, it was just a minor remark.  But I think it's always better to show the correct way of doing things in an answer. :-)

Comment: I'd prefer if the answer just showed the `\newtheorem{exer}{Exercise}` solution without the complication of the new counter that doesn't seem really useful. With `chngcntr`, one can also say `\counterwithin*{exer}{section}` so the `exer` counter is reset when `section` is stepped.

Comment: @egreg: Yes and no (concerning the `exercises` counter). The MWE does not seem to be useful with this `exercises` counter. In this case the  version with the `exer` theorem is better. If there's more background, we could leave the `exercises` counter. That's why I used both 'ideas'... I'll edit the answer and include your suggestion about the `chngcntr` way. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I believe that mixing the two ideas can be confusing for future readers, who might think that the “useless” counter is necessary.